# C++, for, Infinite loop

Tags: c++

My program should get the smallest "g" and the "c" for which 5*c-3*g=p

For example `p=48`

```
5*12-3*4=48
(c=12, g=4)
```

I am stuck in an infinite loop.

I did it two other ways, but I want to do it exactly this way.

```
 #include <iostream.h>
int main()
{int s, c, g, p, a;
cin>>p;
a=0; s=0;
for (g=0; a==0; g++)
 for (c=0; p>s; c++)
  {s=5*c-3*g;  if (s==p) a=1;}

    cout<<c-1<<endl;
    cout<<g-1<<endl;
return 0;}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables (use 'watch' variables)?

Comment: Hint: `for (g=0; a==0; g++)` this loop ends when `a==0`, what values can `a` have here?

Comment: _@JonathanLivingston_ Please use your debugger first, before asking such trivia questions on Stack Overflow. The site's meant to produce quality outcome on real general Questions and Answers, and not debugging help as your personal help-desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, you are changing the value of `s` in inner loop but when the inner loop terminates, you don't reset `s` to `0`. Hence `s == p` never become `true`.

Try this:

```
for (g = 0; a == 0; g++) {
    for (c = 0; p > s; c++) {
        s = 5 * c - 3 * g;
        if (s == p)
            a = 1;
    }
    s = 0; // reset s for next checking
}
```

For input,

> p = 12

The output may be:

> 12
>
> 4

Comment: Always debug to find out this kind of errors, use IDEs like NetBeans, Eclipse, Visual Studios etc which are great for coding. Best of luck.